# Why proc is not recognised in scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

I have taken a concurrency course at the university, and this is my first time I try to program in Scala.

I have copied the following code of Scala as it is in the lectures to compile it.

```
import Extras._
object Test{
var x=0
val P = proc {for (i<-0 until N)x=x+1}

def main(args:Array[String])=
for (y<-0 until 5){x=0;P();println(x)}
}
```

However I get the following error.

```
bash-4.2$ scalac ~/Scala/helloworld
/users/mscs5674/Scala/helloworld:5: error: not found: value proc
val P = proc {for (i<-0 until N)x=x+1}
        ^
one error found
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: `proc` is not a standard Scala thing, you must have imported it from `test.cso`. Ask your professor, or look in the lecture notes if this is explained somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are compiling helloworld you are importing test.cso._

this means you are bringing classes from another jar (a package). you have to specify that package in your classpath, so that the scala compiler is able to use those classes.

`scalac -cp <test.cso.jar` goes here>:`~/Scala/helloworld`

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that in a few hours :)